# Java is not being update after PATH is changed in AIX system

Tags: java, aix

I'm trying to update java 1.6 to java 1.7 in my aix system.

I already installed java 1.7 but when i run     *java -version*
it appear as java 1.6.

I changed the PATH using export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java71/jre/bin:/usr/java71/bin
but still does not work.

Does someone know what i have to do?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.6 is probably EARLIER in the path than 1.7. try `PATH=..7.1 stuff...:$PATH`, so the 1.7 gets added BEFORE anything else.

Comment: Note: you might define a symlink to the latest java: `rm /usr/java; ln -s java71 /usr/java; export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java; /usr/java/bin/java -version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PATH entries on the left take precedence over the right (they're searched first). Change

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/java71/jre/bin:/usr/java71/bin
```

to something like

```
PATH=/usr/java71/jre/bin:/usr/java71/bin:$PATH
```